# Getting garbage value when downloading Word file from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting garbage value when downloading Word file from MySQL database using PHP. The garbage value like:

> PK!0É(r¥[Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TÉnÂ0½Wê?D¾V‰¡‡ªªº[¤Ò0ö¬z“ÇlßI QÕB

Comment: What do you mean by garbage? It looks like .docx file (it's zipped file). If you want to download it using a browser, try to set correct Content-type header. You definitely need to add more detailed description of the problem to get answer.

Comment: The code run on localhost correctly but I am uploading on cpannel get garbage value..

Comment: i am not downloading zipped file , I want to download word file which is stored in database

Comment: garbage means encoded format like             PK!0É(r¥[Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TÉnÂ0½Wê?D¾V‰¡‡ªªº[¤Ò0ö¬z“ÇlßI QÕB \"%ã·øåÙƒÑÚšl µw%ë=–“^i7+ÙÇä%¿g&á”0ÞAÉ6€l4¼¾L60#´Ã’ÍS œ£œƒXøŽ&•V$z3„ü3à·½Þ—Þ%p)O5ž “²ç5}Þ:‰`eÛ…

Comment: @ShekharJangde Why would that be a problem ? What are you expecting ? How is it saved in the DB ? How do you retrieve it ? What is your PHP code ? Why am I asking so many questions ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a perfectly valid `.docx`-file when viewed in a text-editor. Note that all MS-Office formats are some kind of binary format and its a non-trivial process to extract the text-contents.

As for `.docx`: it's basically a bunch of several `.xml`-files that are zipped together - to see those contents just rename it to `.zip`, unpack it with your favorite zip-tool and view the contents - you won't be happy with that either :-(

Comment: // Make sure an ID was passed
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
 
    // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
    if($id <= 0) {
        die('The ID is invalid!');
    }
    else {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('107.151.44.43', 'tajtours_inarrch', 'tajtours@dmin', 'tajtours_chandrapur');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

Comment: $query = "
            SELECT `mime`, `name`, `size`, `data`
            FROM `file`
            WHERE `id` = {$id}";
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);
         if($result) {
                if($result->num_rows == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
                header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']); echo $row['data']; }
            else {   echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
            }

Comment: // Free the mysqli resources
            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        @mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}
?>

Comment: @Shekhar Jangde: this should go into your question (use the edit function) instead of into comments.